# MS Access SQL: query of two tables without having a key?

Tags: sql, loops, ms-access-2010

I have two tables (`NBZ` and `POINTS`) in my MS Access database. Each of these tables contains two columns of X and Y coordinates (a pair of coordinates)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aHBa.png). There is no key between the two tables.

I want to calculate the distance between the coordinate pair from `NBZ` and `POINTS`. The formula is

```
(Sqr(([R_CENTER_GK3]-[LX])^2+([H_CENTER_GK3]-[LY])^2)) AS Distance.
```

But how can the calculation be done in MS Access SQL without having a key (thus no JOIN)?

With the key it looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEFT(A.PAD, 6),
    A.PAD,
    A.PArt,
    A.LX,
    A.LY,
    T.DGN_TEXT,
    T.R_SCHWERPKT_GK3,
    T.H_SCHWERPKT_GK3,
    (Sqr(([T.R_SCHWERPKT_GK3]-[A.LX])^2+([T.H_SCHWERPKT_GK3]-[A.LY])^2)) AS ABSTAND
INTO 
    TESTING_AVANI
FROM 
    AVANI_FPF_SSR0 AS A 
INNER JOIN 
    TESTING_v1 AS T ON T.DGN_TEXT = LEFT(A.PAD, 6)
WHERE 
    (PArt < 'PS2' AND ABSTAND <= 8000)
    OR (PArt >= 'PS2' AND ABSTAND <= 700);
```

I think it has to be done with a FOR loop?!?!

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Cheers
Sina

Comment: The problem is that the select clause gets executed after the from clause. This means you cannot access ABSTAND in the ON clause. Either replace ABSTAND with the whole formula or remove the criteria from the ON clause, so as to combine rows with another ABSTAND, too, and then use the result for a main query where you filter.

Comment: In MS Access, you do not require an index to create a join. An index / key is sometimes required to create an updateable recordset: a work around is to append / create to a table.

Comment: many thanks. Unfortunately, I do not really understand what both of you mean.  Lets say, I do have table NBZ with only NBZ.X and NBZ.Y colums. The second table has only POINT.X and POIN.Y colums. I wanne know the the distances between each point from table NBZ and POINT. I just know the formular for calculating the distance between the two Koordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The old join syntax is still supported by MsAccess (and, indeed by most rdbms vendors). In this syntax you simply list the tables you want to join as a comma separated list, and the join condition(s) and any other condition(s) go to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEFT(A.PAD, 6),
    A.PAD,
    A.PArt,
    A.LX,
    A.LY,
    T.DGN_TEXT,
    T.R_SCHWERPKT_GK3,
    T.H_SCHWERPKT_GK3,
    (Sqr(([T.R_SCHWERPKT_GK3]-[A.LX])^2+([T.H_SCHWERPKT_GK3]-[A.LY])^2)) AS ABSTAND
INTO 
    TESTING_AVANI
FROM 
    AVANI_FPF_SSR0 AS A,
    TESTING_v1 AS T 
WHERE 
    T.DGN_TEXT = LEFT(A.PAD, 6)
    AND ((PArt < 'PS2' AND 
          (Sqr(([T.R_SCHWERPKT_GK3]-[A.LX])^2+([T.H_SCHWERPKT_GK3]-[A.LY])^2)) <= 8000)
         OR 
          (PArt >= 'PS2' AND 
             (Sqr(([T.R_SCHWERPKT_GK3]-[A.LX])^2+([T.H_SCHWERPKT_GK3]-[A.LY])^2)) <= 700))
```

As Thorsten mentioned, you can't use the defined name in the JOIN or WHERE clause; so you have to repeat it in all three locations, and if the tables are very large this can be very slow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. True, there is no JOIN now, however, T.DGN_TEXT = LEFT(A.PAD, 6) does somehow the same.  Lets say, I do have table NBZ with only NBZ.X and NBZ.Y colums. The second table has only POINT.X and POIN.Y colums. I wanne know the the distances between each point from table NBZ and POINT. I just know the formular for calculating the distance between the two Koordinates.

Comment: You don't have to have the`WHERE` condition, at all (or have only a part of it). it will then be a cartesian product: all combinations of rows from tables NBZ and POINT. You will still have the distance formula in `SELECT` and this will give you distances between each point in DGN against all points in NBZ